# How to refill a fire extinguisher

Tags: fire-extinguisher

How do I refill a fire extinguisher in NYC.
I went to the fire department and they do not refill them.
I bought a new one but if the old one can be refilled, I would use it as a backup.

Answer (score 2):

Look in the phone book under "Fire Extinguishers" or similar. In the NYC / Jersey area there should be hundreds of companies that service hand-held extinguishers - everything from hand-pump water cans to stuff that puts out exotic metal fires.

Note that if it is a very small domestic unit it may be cheaper to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

The FD will check them, but not test or refill them. You do need a special place that does this for commercial units. Smaller household units cannot be refilled, they must be replaced.

Here is info from the NYC FD I found in about 2 seconds with Google: http://www.nyc.gov/html/fdny/html/safety/extinguisher/index.shtml
They show links to dozens of fire extinguisher service companies.

Comment: Depending on the age of the unit, (if it is a refillable unit) they may also need to do a "hydro-test" to verify that the tank is in good condition before refilling it. They are usually the cheapest place to perform such a test (scuba tanks also need this test every 5 years, and scuba shops are not the cheapest place to have it done, frequently.)

Answer (score 0):

In my area, I belive fire houses will exchange your dead one for a good one. But I'm not sure if they still do this, it's been a number of years since I've done it. If they can't exchange it, they'll at least be able to tell you who can help you.